# "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error of SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  cust_id      char(10)  NOT NULL ,
  cust_name    char(50)  NOT NULL ,
  cust_address char(50)  NULL ,
  cust_city    char(50)  NULL ,
  cust_state   char(5)   NULL ,
  cust_zip     char(10)  NULL ,
  cust_country char(50)  NULL ,
  cust_contact char(50)  NULL ,
  cust_email   char(255) NULL 
);
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000001', 'Village Toys', '200 Maple Lane', 'Detroit', 'MI', '44444', 'USA', 'John Smith', 'sales@villagetoys.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000002', 'Kids Place', '333 South Lake Drive', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43333', 'USA', 'Michelle Green');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000003', 'Fun4All', '1 Sunny Place', 'Muncie', 'IN', '42222', 'USA', 'Jim Jones', 'jjones@fun4all.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000004', 'Fun4All', '829 Riverside Drive', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', '88888', 'USA', 'Denise L. Stephens', 'dstephens@fun4all.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000005', 'The Toy Store', '4545 53rd Street', 'Chicago', 'IL', '54545', 'USA', 'Kim Howard');

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  order_num  int      NOT NULL ,
  order_date date     NOT NULL ,
  cust_id    char(10) NOT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20005, TO_DATE('2012-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '1000000001');
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20006, TO_DATE('2012-01-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '1000000003');
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20007, TO_DATE('2012-01-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '1000000004');
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20008, TO_DATE('2012-02-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '1000000005');
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20009, TO_DATE('2012-02-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '1000000001');
```

It is interesting that if I run:

```
SELECT count(*) AS order_count,
  (SELECT cust_name
   FROM customers
   WHERE customers.cust_id=orders.cust_id) AS cust_name,
   cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

There is no error.

But if I create a new table and run a similar code:

```
CREATE TABLE orders2 AS SELECT * FROM orders
SELECT count(*) AS order_count,
  (SELECT cust_id
   FROM orders2
   WHERE orders2.cust_id=orders.cust_id) AS cust_id2,
   cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

It gives me an error: `single-row subquery returns more than one row`

So why did this happen? I know what the error message is. According to the document, this error is triggered if "The outer query must use one of the keywords ANY, ALL, IN, or NOT IN to specify values to compare because the subquery returned more than one row." is not satisfied. But I can not understand why the first code is eligible but the second code is not.

DBMS: Oracle 11

Comment: There are multiple rows in `orders2` for the same `cust_id`

Comment: Can't understand your expectation. First you use table `customers` then you create other table not copy from `customers` but using `orders`, then use query for that table and say that is "similar"? The error is clearly because of the duplicate cust_id `1000000001` in your table `orders` and its copy table `orders2`

Comment: Your second query uses a copy of `orders` in its subquery. Your first uses `customers`. Your code may be similar, but your data is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

Dude u have duplicate cust_id '1000000001' and how to expect the sql to work out. Can u be more elaborate on ur requirement. Can see many of them are not clear with ur question.

Its kind of baseless coz if multiple (duplicate) Cust_id's are there then surely Oracle will through you this error message.

Using Distinct has solved the query and am not getting any more error messages.

```
SELECT count(*) AS order_count,
  (SELECT distinct cust_id
FROM orders2
WHERE orders2.cust_id=orders.cust_id) AS cust_id2,
cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Please correct me if my suggestion is wrong as clearly u should be able to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the failing statement, more even i don't see why you need a orders2 table.
Anyway, i'm guessing you want a count of the orders for each customer id, if so i see no need for a subselect, you can just do

```
SELECT count(*) AS order_count, cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand the difference:

Because you don't seem to have a PK on your Customers table at the moment, do the following:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000005', 'DUPLICATE CUST_ID', '4545 53rd Street', 'Chicago', 'IL', '54545', 'USA', 'Kim Howard');
```

- Then try running your first query again. *You should observe that it now also fails with the same error*.
- Conversely, if you just perform a parse-check on the second query **without running** it: you won't get an error, because it ***is** syntactically correct*.

> So why did this happen?

Your code is similar, but your data is different. The error is triggered by a ***data problem*** detected when the query is ***executed***. *This error cannot be detected when the query is only compiled*.

> But I can not understand why the first code is eligible but the second code is not.

The ***code*** in both queries is valid. It's just that the sub-query is returning too many rows when it's executed for some `orders.cust_id` values.

This is why you have to be very careful about the cardinality of relationships when constructing such queries. If you make a mistake, the queries can run successfully for years, and then suddenly break when an extra row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The select:

```
SELECT count(*) AS order_count,
  (SELECT cust_id
   FROM orders2
   WHERE orders2.cust_id=orders.cust_id) AS cust_id2,
   cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

is differetn of select:

```
    SELECT count(*) AS order_count,
  (SELECT cust_name
   FROM customers
   WHERE customers.cust_id=orders.cust_id) AS cust_name,
   cust_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Because you create the second table from Orders and not from Custmer:

```
CREATE TABLE orders2 AS SELECT * FROM orders
```

And the line cupplicate is with cust_id`=1000000001